# IDIV Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I was trying to make a calculator that can read signed integers and add, subtract, multiply and divide. So I made a function (recebe_int) which reads a integer (inteiro1), then I push it's value and read another integer (inteiro2). To test if the operation succeeds, I'm printing the result (resultado) as it's ASCII representative.

My only problem so far is the division operation, every other operation is working. When I use the division part of the calculator, it gives a random result.

Here is the code that calls the reader function for both integers and the IDIV operation:

```
push inteiro1
push num1
push 11
call recebe_int       
push dword [inteiro1] 

push inteiro2
push num2
push 11
call recebe_int 

pop edx
mov eax, edx
cdq
idiv dword [inteiro2] 

mov dword [resultado], eax

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, resultado
mov edx, 1
int 80h
```

Comment: `mov eax, edx` where is `edx` set? Isn't your number in `inteiro1`? So why not do `mov eax, [inteiro1]`?

Comment: Oops, I didn't put pop edx here. I'm going to edit.

Comment: What's the calling convention for `recebe_int`? Does it remove the arguments? Does it work with just `mov eax, [inteiro1]`? You do not expect human readable text on output, right?

Comment: Inteiro1 is the address which has the int version of the string num1 that will be read in recebe_int, and 11 is its max size. No, it doesn't work well with mov eax, [inteiro1]. And no, I expect only a ASCII character that represents the result of the operation for now. For example, if I have 80/2, the result is 40, so it will print (.

Comment: Waiiiiit, are your inputs numbers or strings? Your code expects numbers. Does `recebe_int` read a string into the `numX` and then convert it to integer in `inteiroX`?

Comment: They are read as strings but are changed into integers in recebe_int, exactly like you described.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the following version I have replaced your `recebe_int` calls (that you did not provide code for) with just setting the input numbers to `80` and `2` and I get `(` printed as expected.

```
extern exit
global main
main:
mov dword [inteiro1], 80
mov dword [inteiro2], 2

push dword [inteiro1] 
pop edx
mov eax, edx
cdq
idiv dword [inteiro2] 

mov dword [resultado], eax

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, resultado
mov edx, 1
int 80h

jmp exit

section .data
inteiro1: dd 0
inteiro2: dd 0
resultado: dd 0
```

Whatever issue you are having is elsewhere. The fact that you pass `11` as length to `recebe_int` seems to indicate you are trying to use strings for calculations without converting to number first. Also, use a debugger to gather more information.